# Doing Cucumber/Rspec tests for embedded code (Google Data Studio)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, looker-studio

Currently, I have a ruby on rails app which includes a dashboard that was created in Google Data Studio and embedded into it.
However, while doing tests on it, I realised that I'm unable to view the resources within the embedded iframe. Is there any way to access this, by perhaps editing the env.rb file?

features/support/env.rb

```
require 'cucumber/rails'
ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false

begin
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
rescue NameError
  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
end

Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation
Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_tests = false
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `within_frame` to move the current context into an embedded iframe - https://rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/Capybara/Session#within_frame-instance_method